# Scrolling a view from another view

Tags: android

I have a Horizontal Scroll view in my layout. It contains a a linear layout(orientation vertical) which in turn contains buttons. in this area I can horizontally scroll (The buttons don't fit together in one screen at a time in most phones). Android provides me this comfort. Now below this horizontal scroll view, there is a Relative layout. 
Now what I want is, when I swipe horizontally in the Relative Layout, I want the buttons in the horizontal scroll view to scroll.
I have tried to implement this by overriding the `onTouchEvent()`. The problem with this is that, the buttons scroll infinitely(they go out of the screen). I am not able to put a limit. I tried to put a limit. But some how it exceeds the limit by 1 and stops. Then I am not able to scroll.
**This is my layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"  
        android:id="@+id/llt"
        >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
       android:text="Groups" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/login1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:text="QandA"/>
                <Button 
            android:id="@+id/login2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
            style="@style/ButtonText" 
            android:text="Pending Requests"/>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/login3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:text="Settings"
            ></Button>
                        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/login4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonText" 
            android:text="Help"/>
    </LinearLayout>        
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/rl1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   >
    .
    .
    .
```

**This is what I have tried :**

```
@Override 
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
           currentX = (int) event.getRawX();
           currentY = (int) event.getRawY();
           break;
       }

       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
           int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
           int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();
           if(location1[0]<=leftconst&&(location2[0]+rightmost.getWidth())>=rightconst)
           {
           llt.scrollBy(currentX - x2 ,0);
           }
           currentX = x2;
           currentY = y2;
           break;
       }   
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
           break;
       }
   }
     return true; 
 }
```

`leftconst` and `rightconst` are equal to 3 and `screenwidth`, respectively. But when scrolling it it stops a both ends. Then after that scrolling is not possible. `leftmost` is the button with id `login` and `rightmost` is the button with id `login4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing my own code more deeply, I found that the limits made the scrolling stop forever(it should not stop if the user is scrolling the other way). So I have added another check in the if statement to the check the **direction of scrolling** (by storing the previous position).

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
           int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
           int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();
           int location1[] = new int[2];
           int location2[]=new int[2];
           leftmost.getLocationOnScreen(location1);
           rightmost.getLocationOnScreen(location2);
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if((x2-currentX<0||location1[0]+1<leftconst)&&((location2[0]+rightmost.getWidth())+1>rightconst||x2-currentX>0))
           {
           llt.scrollBy(currentX - x2 ,0);
           }
           currentX = x2;
           currentY = y2;
           break;
       }
```

**Edit**
A more better and simpler solution without the if statement itself. Instead of scrolling the `LinearLayout`(llt), just scroll the `**HorizontalScrollView**` itself! There is no need to specify any limit as the `HorizontalScrollView` takes care of that.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
           int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
           int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();
           hscrv.scrollBy(currentX - x2 ,0);
           currentX = x2;
           currentY = y2;
           break;
       }
```

`hscrv` is the horizontal scroll view containing the linear layout and the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `scrollBy` use `scrollTo(x2)`, this will scroll more accurately. Using scrollBy is confusing in your code.

The parameter to `scrollTo` can be calculated like this

```
final float ratio = horizontalscrollView_width/relativelayout_width;
```

then in onTouch

```
scrollTo( x2 * ratio, 0);
```

You can use `VelocityTracker` to implement fling feature after you successfully done with scrolling..

Comment: It is not about the accuracy. I have edited the last part of my question. the problem is that once it reaches an end, the scrolling stops because of the limit specified in the if statement.

Comment: why do you need to specify the limit?

Comment: Otherwise it keeps scrolling and the buttons disappear from the screen(it scrolls infinitely).

Comment: thanks for answering. I found the answer. Please see my answer.

Comment: good if something works.. but try to do it without the if statement.. will become faster..

Comment: Why do you say "without the if statement". Without the if statement, the scrolling would be infinite. One more question - you have used ratio is your code. Why is that? Why use the ratio?

Comment: Posted a more simpler solution without IF statement:P

Comment: Thats what i meant. I never understood why you were using the if.. Anyways you figured it out yourself, rather than me banging my  head to explain it to you.. congrats..

Comment: Why use the ratio?.. For e.g. say your relative layout width is 100, and your horizontal scrollview width is 1000. so when you finger is moving on 50th pixel, the horizontal scrollview should be on the 500th.. so the currentX * ratio = 50*10 = 500th pixel in the scrollview. this will scroll the scrollview even if you just tap somewhere on the relative layout..

Comment: The reason I used if was that I was not scrolling the HorizontalScrollView. I was trying to scroll the LinearLayout inside the horizontal scroll view.